Continuous marginal densities from joint density
I have a seemingly simple question, but I cannot find a solution which is why I am asking the community. The question has two parts.
I am given a multivariate probability density $f: \mathbb{R}^d\to [0,\infty)$.

First, I am searching for conditions such that the marginal densities of $f$ are continuous. Further, I would like functions of the form $h_{y_2,\ldots,y_d}(x_1):=\int_{-\infty}^{y_2} ,\ldots,\int_{-\infty}^{y_d} f(x_1,\ldots,x_d) dx_2,\ldots dx_d$ to be continuous for all $y_2,\ldots,y_d\in \mathbb{R}\cup\{\infty\}$.
Second, I am searching for conditions on $f$ and $h_{y_2,\ldots,y_d}$ such that its derivatives exists and are continous. Further, I would also like them to be bounded as well.

Assuming that $f$ is continuous is not enough to ensure 1. as this post shows.
I tried to assume that $f$ and all its associated margins are continous and twice differentiable with uniformly bounded derivatives to solve 2., but I always get stuck. So I guess even this strong condition is not enough.
Any partial solution is appreciated.
